# Azure DevOps pipeline tool to deploy Angular application to AWS Amplify

Tags: angular

Does anyone know of a plugin within Azure DevOps pipeline to integrate AWS amplify.  I specifically need to deploy an Angular aplication to AWS amplify through the Azure DevOps pipeline.  If you ask why, it is because we are tied up using Azure DevOps as the project management and build tool.